# Respond_to format in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am having problems getting respond_to format working in Rails 5 app in controller, is just for downloading a csv list of users, as below:

```
def customers_graylist_export
    @graylisted_users = Customer.where(status_trust: 'graylist')
    respond_to do |format|
    format.csv do
      response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/csv'
      response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; 
      filename=ListaCinza.csv"
    end
  end
end
```

And getting unknown format error on line "respond_to do |format|"  the mime type is registered in mime_types initializer, and this should be straightforward, but Rails 5 is a little quirky!

Any suggestions welcome?

Many Thanks

Comment: Including the actual error and trace would help.
Unless the route has CSV as the default format the URL must specify format. E.G `localhost:3000/path/to/customers_graylist_export.csv`
Otherwise it defaults to `format.html`, which is missing here. Could be the cause.

Comment: Ok, I eventually switched to running a service object and building it that way. Route doesnt have a format so thats likely why. Thanks